# Reproducing figure from paper on hydrodynamics

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve Eqn. on Page 674 of https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3667.pdf I shall quote the relevant paragraph :

> Next, we proceed to analyse the nonlocal response in a strip with
> transverse current injected and drained through a pair of contacts, as
> pictured in Fig. 1(a). Unlike the above case of longitudinal current,
> here the potential profile is not set externally but must be obtained
> from equation (3). The analysis is facilitated by introducing a stream
> function via $v = \hat{z}$ × ∇ $\psi$ , which solves the
> incompressibility condition. At first we will completely ignore the
> ohmic effects, setting α and γp to zero as above, which leads to a
> biharmonic equation $(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2)^2\psi = 0$ with the
> boundary conditions $v_x$ = 0, $v_y$ =$I$δ(x) for y =$0,w$.

The geometry is $(x,y)\in [0,l]\times[0,w]$ and $l \gg w$.
The equation to solve is $\nabla^2\nabla^2\psi = 0$ where $\psi$ is the stream function. I write this as two coupled laplacians, $\nabla^2\psi = u$ and $\nabla^2 u = 0$. The boundary conditions are current injected at $y=0,w$.  The current injected is $I = n e \delta(x)$, and I can model the delta as a lorentzian, so $I = n e v_y = n e \frac{1}{(x/a)^2+1}$, i.e., $v_y = \frac{1}{(x/a)^2+1}$, and since $v = \hat{z}\times\partial\psi = (-\partial_y\psi, \partial_x\psi)$, we have $\partial_x\psi = \frac{1}{(x/a)^2+1}$, thus $\psi = \tan^{-1}(x/a)$ at $y=0,w$ and $u = \nabla^2\psi = \frac{-2x}{a^2}\frac{1}{(x/a)^2+1}$ at $y = 0,w$. At $x=0,l$ I have set $\psi$ constant at $x=0,l$.

The physical picture that one should get is Figure 1 of the paper, which has vortices, which looks like :
[image]

I cannot seem to reproduce these vortices. I model the $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$. My code is below :

```
L1 = 35 ; H1 = 5  ; \[CapitalOmega]1 = 
 Rectangle[{-L1/2, -H1/2}, {L1/2, H1/
   2}] ; RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]1, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

mesh1 = ToElementMesh[ \[CapitalOmega]1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

 biharmonic = { Laplacian[psi2[x, y], {x, y}] == u2[x, y], 
   Laplacian[u2[x, y], {x, y}] == 0};

bcond = {DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == ArcTan[x], y == -H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] ==  ArcTan[x], y == H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == -((2 x)/(x^2 + 1)^2), y == -H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == -((2 x)/(x^2 + 1)^2) , y == H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] ==  1, x == -L1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] ==  -1, x == L1/2]};

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
soln = NDSolve[{biharmonic, bcond}, {psi2, u2}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh1]];

StreamDensityPlot[
 Evaluate[{-Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y], 
    Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y]} /. soln[[1]]], 
 Element[{x, y}, mesh1], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> cool, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Experts, am I doing something wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Include `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]` before `mesh1 = ToElementMesh...`

Comment: What were the error messeges that you got when you ran the code?

Comment: @YSP No error messages, does not match physical picture

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks. Good catch, I was copy pasting blocks of code and well...but I don't think that was the problem because I had already loaded the package on this notebook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't reproduce picture from the paper cited since they used Fourie integral on $-\infty \le x \le \infty$. With FEM we can reproduce part of picture be crossing side vortexes as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

L1 = 2; H1 = 1; \[CapitalOmega]1 = 
 Rectangle[{-L1/2, -H1/2}, {L1/2, H1/2}];

mesh1 = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002]; mesh1["Wireframe"]

biharmonic = {Laplacian[psi2[x, y], {x, y}] == u2[x, y], 
   Laplacian[u2[x, y], {x, y}] == 0};

bcond = {DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == -UnitStep[x], y == -H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == -UnitStep[x], y == H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[{psi2[x, y] == -y^2 + (H1/2)^2, u2[x, y] == 0}, 
    x == -L1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[{psi2[x, y] == y^2 - (H1/2)^2 - 1, 
     u2[x, y] == 0}, x == L1/2]};

soln = NDSolve[{biharmonic, bcond}, {psi2, u2}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh1]];


Show[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[Norm[{-Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y], 
      Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y]} /. soln[[1]]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh1], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "MintColors", PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
 StreamPlot[
  Evaluate[{-Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y], 
     Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y]} /. soln[[1]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh1], StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> Magenta]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. We also can reproduce vortexes by adding two logarithmic singularities as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

L1 = 3; H1 = 1; \[CapitalOmega]1 = 
 Rectangle[{-L1/2, -H1/2}, {L1/2, H1/2}];

mesh1 = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002]; mesh1["Wireframe"]

biharmonic = {Laplacian[psi2[x, y], {x, y}] == u2[x, y], 
   Laplacian[u2[x, y], {x, y}] == 0};

bcond = {DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == -UnitStep[x], y == -H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == -UnitStep[x], y == H1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[{psi2[x, y] == -Log[(x + H1)^2 + y^2], 
     u2[x, y] == 0}, x == -L1/2], 
   DirichletCondition[{psi2[x, y] == Log[(x - H1)^2 + y^2] - 1, 
     u2[x, y] == 0}, x == L1/2]};

soln = NDSolve[{biharmonic, bcond}, {psi2, u2}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh1]];

      

Show[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[Norm[{-Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y], 
      Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y]} /. soln[[1]]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh1], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "MintColors", PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
 StreamPlot[
  Evaluate[{-Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y], 
     Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y]} /. soln[[1]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh1], StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> Magenta]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 2. We also can use Fourie series as follows

```
 Clear[p]

nmax = 50; L = 65; 
psi[x_, y_] := Sum[Sin[ Pi n/L  x] p[n][y], {n, nmax}]; 
k[n_] := Pi n/L; 
psix[x_, y_] := Sum[k[n] Cos[k[n]  x] p[n][y], {n, nmax}];

c[n_] = FourierSinCoefficient[-UnitStep[x], x, n]

sol1 = DSolve[{k[n]^4 - 2 k[n]^2 D[pn[y], {y, 2}] + D[pn[y], {y, 4}] ==
       0, pn[-1/2] == c[n], pn[1/2] == c[n], pn'[-1/2] == 0, 
     pn'[1/2] == 0}, pn[y], y] // FullSimplify;

p[m_][y_] := (pn[y] /. sol1[[1]]) /. n -> m

p1[n_][y_] := D[pn[y] /. sol1[[1]], y]

psiy[x_, y_] := Sum[Sin[k[n]  x] p1[n][y], {n, nmax}];

StreamDensityPlot[
 Evaluate[{-psiy[x, y], psix[x, y]}], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, .5}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
 ColorFunction -> "MintColors"]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Alex, that makes sense. Guess need to do something like Show[MapAt[Translate[#, {-L1, 0}] &, plot, 1], plot, 
 MapAt[Translate[#, {L1, 0}] &, plot, 1], PlotRange -> All] to get a periodic picture. Let me think about this a bit more before I accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: @Charlie Please, see Update 2 to my answer.